# D prime equation in python -spyder

Tags: python

```
def dprime(gen_scores, imp_scores):

    x = 1 # replace 1 with the numerator

    y = 1 # replace 1 with the denominator

    return x / y
```

In place of x and y, we use d' equation and I am not sure how to replace x and y with. Can someone help. I imported two libraries [ import numpy as np &
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt]
The goal is to plot nodes on images

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the D-prime value, we would implement the following equation:

[image]

Mu_g here would be the mean of your 'gen_scores' list, and Mu_i would be the mean of the 'imp_scores' list. The following Greek symbols in your denominator are your variances.

Seeing as you have imported numpy, we can implement the equation of D-prime by:

```
numerator = np.sqrt(2)*abs(np.mean(gen_scores)-np.mean(imp_scores))
```

I know this is a homework question, so I'll leave it to you to implement the denominator.